# Why would roast beef broth turn white?

Tags: food-safety

It had nothing added to it.  I always boil the roast to tenderize.  The broth is a milky white and I have never seen this happen before.  Is it safe to eat?

Comment: It sounds like you have suspended albumens clouding the broth, but it is hard to say from the limited description.  Was there anything unusual in this batch?   How does it smell?  Can you provide a picture?

Comment: Number 2 rule of food service:  when in doubt, throw it out.

Comment: Good discussion of why you might want to intentionally cloud the broth here: http://www.seriouseats.com/2012/02/how-to-make-tonkotsu-ramen-broth-at-home-recipe.html The broth should be safe to eat but the mouthfeel will be completely different due to the emulsified fats.

Comment: Also, how old is the broth? If it has become milky after some storage time, it could be a bad sign.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have emulsified the fat from the meat into the broth. This will happen if you don't skim the fat and then cook at a rolling boil. The oil droplets will become very fine and disperse light, which is what causes the broth to appear white. If that is in fact the cause of the whiteness, it isn't a safety risk.

Comment: Just to be clear - assuming that's the answer (and I believe it is), yes, it's safe to eat.

Comment: Quite right; editing answer.